# ios10.0 system jump to the system settings, the system set the interface appears flash back

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

My problem is more than ios10.0 system jump to the system settings, the system set the interface appears flash back, but app itself is nothing, the problem is the occasional appearance, I use the xcode8.1. puzzled me for a long time, hope to get the answer.

[image]

I am here to jump to the system settings interface is configured in the project.

[image]

My code is like the above figure.

Comment: I'm afraid your problem description is very hard to follow, as it seems you've used Google Translate (or similar). Which has produced incorrect English. Please edit your post to provide a clear description of your problem, _and_ a description of what you want to see. Also, please post the code itself in your posts, and not just link to an image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.My problem is that Apple ios10.0 system jump to the system settings interface, the system settings interface flashback but the app itself did not flash back, the problem is occasionally, I use xcode8.1. Confused me for a long time, hoping to get the answer, thank you!